# Flutter Android application stopped to build after last Flutter update

Tags: android, flutter

My new flutter version follows:

```
Flutter 3.13.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d211f42860 (7 days ago) • 2023-10-25 13:42:25 -0700
Engine • revision 0545f8705d
Tools • Dart 3.1.5 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

After upgrade I see following build error:

```
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform firebase-analytics-ktx-21.5.0.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.5.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Vitaliy\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\41525bdf5de3383fe28a17aaa9610b1b\transformed\jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-21.5.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:21.5.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Vitaliy\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ce1b8deb6ac5da9f5a47c5868d41ba4c\transformed\jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

How to bypass this bug and still build the application?

Clearing caches, removing `.gradle` and similar folders change nothing.

Comment: Have you updated your versions of firebase analytics and play services in the pubspec.yaml?

Comment: @Wheathin I use latest versions of these Flutter packages: firebase_analytics: ^10.6.3, firebase_core: ^2.21.0, firebase_messaging: ^14.7.3.

Comment: Seems like the issue is with this: `Failed to transform firebase-analytics-ktx-21.5.0.aar`

Comment: @tomerpacific Sure; the question is what the issue and why updating Flutter version triggers it.

Comment: In my project I had to upgrade the kotlin version. In project_folder/android/build.gradle on line 2:     `ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'`

Comment: @Wheathin I can not do that, because I have some components incompatible with so new Kotlin. Default Kotlin version for Android Studio is 1.7.10 now. Actually new Flutter version corrupted project so much, that even downgrade back to previous Flutter version and all plugins didn't help. so I ended with unpacking project backup from ZIP archive. I actually never saw before that attempt to upgrade Flutter version may deeply corrupt the project.

Answer (score 7):

For me, the issue comes from adding `built_value: 8.7.0` in the dependencies (either directly or indirectly), while using `firebase_analytics` plugin. And it will only occur if your app level(android/app/) `build.gradle` `compileSdkversion` is 34. An issue was created on [flutterfire repo](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11853) so lets wait for the fix.

One temporary workaround would be either

- Reduce the compileSdkversion to 33 if its set to 34
- Use older version of `built_value`

I didn't need to change anything else so see what works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, it seems this is some kind of bug. Downgrading to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
```

seems to resolve this. More info could be found here:
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11853

Answer (score 0):

Add in `pubspec.yaml:`

```
dependency_overrides:
  built_value: 8.6.3
```

Good bye problem;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it without downgrading the version flutter by doing the following:

Overriding the version of build_version package.

```
dependency_overrides:
    built_value: 8.6.0
```

Using version 7.3.0 of gradle in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Changing the following linne in the android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

After I set flutter.targetSdkVersion from 33 to 34
It started to give this error

I Downgraded from 7.2.4. to 7.3.0

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    }
}
```